# Can I use Android 4.4 api for lower version like 2.3?

Tags: android, sdk

I would like to know if I use for example ADT with android 4.4, then when I finished my application, does my application run on lower version of android or is everything ok with using Android 4.4 api?
Thanks for any guides.

Comment: Higher API versions are not always backwards compatible, if that's what you're asking. See the docs for "minVersion" info

Comment: thanks, then I should install lower version of api? would it better to only write in for example version 2.3? for hight capability.

Comment: [Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) a good read. Scroll down to **Uses of API Level in Android**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `api level 10` i.e `android 2.3.3` may not have that are in `Api level 19` i.e `android 4.4`

For Example

- Renderscript
- Actionbar
- Fragments
- keyboard support 

  etc

  then you would have to use the support library to use the above in lower end devices or phones with lower api.

Simply changing your `android:minSdkVersion` to lower version in your  `manifest file` may result to app crash or force close...

Comment: I think the best option is to use 2.3.3 api for higher capability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you define the code in Manifest.xml exactly, like this :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Should notice `android:minSdkVersion="10"` (Android 2.3.3).

Comment: Thanks, then it would be no problem with lower capability yes?

Comment: Yes.  Can run on lower version of android device. Everything OK with using Android 4.4 api.